# Unable to read .xpt file from s3 raw bucket using pandas.read_sas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a SAS transport file(.xpt) which is present in S3 raw bucket using pandas.read_sas method but getting error

`AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import xport

"""after setting the S3 bucket details-this is how I am trying to read xpt"""

dr1=pd.read_sas("s3://" + mybucket_name + "/test.xpt", format="xport")
```

this is where I am getting error `"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'"`

Answer (score 1):

I got success after I downgraded my pandas version to 0.23.4. It seems like pandas versions 0.25.x have some issue reading .xpt files from S3 bucket.